# HTML table - can one indent occasional rows?

Tags: html, css, formatting, css-tables

I have a customer production report which is produced in the form of an *HTML table*. The customer would now like some *additional detail on certain of the report lines*.

*So the existing report has lines that look like:*

```
+----------+-----+-----+-----+
| Widget 1 | 123 | 456 | 789 |
| Widget 2 | 200 | 500 | 300 |
| Widget 3 | 555 | 222 | 999 |
+----------+-----+-----+-----+
```

*And what they now want is:*

```
+----------+-----+-----+-----+
| Widget 1 | 123 | 456 | 789 |
| Widget 2 | 200 | 500 | 300 |
|   this   | 100 | 200 | 150 |
|   that   |  75 | 250 | 100 |
|   other  |  25 |  50 |  50 |
| Widget 3 | 555 | 222 | 999 |
+----------+-----+-----+-----+
```

The lines for `this`, `that` and `other` are the **detail** lines, which should be shown in distinctive (smaller) fonts. That part I have managed, but getting these lines to display indented (as shown) has been elusive.

The report already used CSS elements `td.item-heading` and `td.item-data` to format the existing row headings and data. I tried adding a new `td.detail-heading` and `td.detail-data`, which worked as far as reducing the font sizes were concerned, but the `padding` attribute does not seem to take any effect. The lines of CSS responsible are:

```
td.item-heading {font: 12pt "Arial"; text-align: left}
td.detail-heading {font: 10pt "Arial"; text-align: left; padding 20px}
```

Why does this not give me a 20px indent on the detail lines compared to the item lines?

Comment: You need a colon on your padding line

Comment: you wrote padding 20px , and not padding: 20px; :)

Comment: Groan... Yes. And then I need to use "text-indent" rather than padding to achieve what I really want. Been off sick a whole week... and clearly need another couple of days to get a clear head back!!